# Choose between two different date ranges

Tags: sql

I have a check box, when checked, my date range flips causing me now to choose which date range to look at.

So, 4/15/14 thru 4/20/14 … when my check box is checked, this date range is now 4/10/14 thru 4/15/14.

In my SQL Select I need to chose, based on this check box, which date range.

This didn't work ??

```
Where ( ? Between Date_1 and Date_2 ) or ( ? Between Date_2 and Date_1 )
```

Nor did this work ??

```
Where ( ?
Case
When Ck_Bx Is Null
Then Date_2 and Date_1
Else Date_1 and Date_2
End
)
```

Here is the SQL THAT IS WORKING AND I AM TRYING TO MODIFY THE "WHERE CLAUSE"

```
ExecuteSQL ( " 

Select ToDo_Name_Calc, ToDo_Name

From ToDo  

WHERE ( ( ? Between ToDo_Alert_Date and ToDo_Date ) or ( ? Between ToDo_Date and ToDo_Alert_Date ) ) and ToDo_Ck_Bx Is Null

Order By ToDo_Alert_Date Asc " ; " - " ; "" ;

cDateOfFirstPortal +11  )
```

Any assistance I would be grateful.

Tom

Comment: Did you make a mistake with the dates? You say the dates 'flip' but they are different: "4/15/14 thru 4/20/14" becomes "4/10/14 thru 4/15/14". Shouldn't it be "4/20/14 thru 4/15/14"?

Comment: What dbms type (vendor) are you using? Date handling differs a great deal amongst the databases. (& Please note `between` is not best practice for date ranges, regardless of dbms type.)

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but why is `between` not good practice?

Comment: It isn't off topic in my view, very relevant to this question. Please see my answer below.

Comment: although I've had a crack at this answer, I'm really just guessing what you actually do with the date values

Answer (score 0):

`between` is really just a syntax shortcut and it is the exact equivalent of:
 ( `field` >= small-value and `field` <= larger-value )

Let's say we use 2014-04-20 as the larger-value, but the `field` contains time as well as date. So evaluating <= 2014-04-20 against a stored value of 2014-04-20 11:12:13 means that value is ignored. In truth we really do want that value included (it occurs DURING the day of 2014-04-20) and the most reliable way of protecting we don't make that mistake is to get all data that is less than 2014-04-21.

So, the greatest problem faced when using date ranges using between is that you could miss almost 24 hours of data if you get it wrong. A safer approach avoids this problem by using less than for the upper date - but you add one day to it, and because we need to add one day we may have to use database specific code (e.g. date_add() for MySQL, dateadd() for SQL Server/Sybase).

Not using between, which is the safer option, requires some date arithmetic, represent here simply by +1

```
SELECT
      ToDo_Name_Calc
    , ToDo_Name

FROM ToDo

WHERE (
          ? >= ToDo_Alert_Date AND ? < (ToDo_Date+1) --*
          AND ToDo_Ck_Bx IS NULL)
      OR (
          ? >= ToDo_Date AND ? < (ToDo_Alert_Date+1) --*
          AND ToDo_Ck_Bx IS NOT NULL
         )

ORDER BY
      ToDo_Alert_Date ASC
```

--* use the relevant date addition method for your dbms.

Another reason for not using `between` here is that the dates MUST be in a specific order or nothing is returned', the older date must be first, the younger date must be last. You cannot just reverse them inside the between syntax.

Comment: I don't agree with that. If you know how to handle `BETWEEN` it's a nice shortcut. Let's assume you have two parameters *STARTDATE* and *ENDDATE*, then the order of the two parameters isn't exchangable in your proposition as well. So it's the same situation and no disadvantage in using `between`. If you really have the situation, that you don't want to include the *STARTDATE* and/or the *ENDDATE* in your range you still can use your proposition. So in my opinion, if you are using `BETWEEN` how it's meant to be and you *know* what it does, it *is* a nice shortcut and not bad practice.

Comment: I agree that you cannot reverse the date values in the >= and < approach either, that wasn't the point I'm trying to make. It is due to the fact that BOTH the lower and upper boundaries are included that you cannot rely on between as it produces overlaps. Avoidance tactics (to hold on to the proposition that between is useful) see silly deductions from the upper boundary like 1 second. That is an anti-pattern that produces potential gaps as it fails if the precision is measured in milliseconds.

Comment: The most reliable method, which works for any time precision in the data, is to use a combination of >= with < adding one time unit to the upper value. It isn't hard, it isn't hard to read and maintain, it isn't slower, but it is more accurate and reliable, and it works without needing to know the time precision of the data;  plus it continues to work if the time precision changes (such as MySQL's improvement in time precision from second to millisecond).

Comment: Not using between for date ranges works in all circumstances because it defines mutually exclusive ranges. Achieving mutually exclusive date ranges is difficult using between and if you put the effort in to do it that way you loose the ease of use argument immediately. Another anti-pattern used to make between workable is to "round" date/time to date only using functions on the data (which adversely affects performance). You are free to use between, but I will always caution against it for date/time.

Comment: perhaps this blog will help make the point I have such trouble explaining:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Thanks for the detailled explanation ;-). I understand the problem, that you see in using `BETWEEN`. I don't say it's the perfect mean for everything. But what I am trying to say is, that there are cases where you *explicitly* want both boundaries to be included and for these `BETWEEN` is just perfect. That then has nothing to do with *bad practice*.

Comment: I actually used the term "not best practice"; using between can be bad practice in financial reports where (for example) transactions may be flowing 24x7 (365/6 days of the year). Some SQL users do not understand the issue and can even believe that between is designed for date ranges - they are who my message is aimed at. Between isn't inherently bad, but it can be used badly.